# How to merge two text files with alternating lines?

Tags: python, merge, alternate

I need to read two text files and write their alternating lines to a third file. For example:

File1:

```
A1  
A2
```

File2:

```
B1  
B2
```

Output file:

```
A1  
B1  
A2  
B2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from itertools import zip_longest
with open(filename1) as f1, open(filename2) as f2, open(outfilename, 'w') as of:
    for lines in zip_longest(f1, f2):
        for line in lines:
            if line is not None: print(line, file=of, end='')
```

EDIT: to fix the problem in cases where the input files don't end with a newline, you change the `print` line to this:

```
print(line.rstrip(), file=of)
```

Comment: The code worked good until the last line.  Results on the output file were A1 on the first line, B1 on the second line and A2B2 on the third line.  How can we have the last line (B2) inserted into the last 4th line?

Answer (score 0):

Since files are iterables, they can be `zip`ed together. Since we want to support a case where number of lines in both input files does not match, we use `zip_longest` instead of built-in `zip`. This approach does not require loading whole file to memory, so it can be used to merge even a very big files without getting a `MemoryError`.

```
import itertools

with open('file1.txt') as src1, open('file2.txt', 'r') as src2, open('output.txt', 'w') as dst:
    for line_from_first, line_from_second in itertools.zip_longest(src1, src2):
        if line_from_first is not None:
            dst.write(line_from_first)
        if line_from_second is not None:
            dst.write(line_from_second)
```

Comment: The code worked good until the last line.  Results on the output file were A1 on the first line, B1 on the second line and A2B2 on the third line.  How can we have the last line (B2) inserted into the last 4th line?

Comment: Although @shx2 gave me solution for his code and it worked...I'm still interested in your code because it doesn't load whole file into memory.  When you get opportunity I'd be interested in your solution to the last line not concatenating with next to last line.  Thanks!

Comment: I simply does not modify read lines - if last line in one of files does not end with newline character, I don't append it explicitly. It would be fairly easy to fix by checking if last char of line string (`line[-1]`) is or isn't a newline.